# Python problem with adding table to Database with sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Hi, I’m trying to create a function that will take a table in insert(add) to the database.**
**My Code :**

```
def save_database(table_name):
        table_name.head(0).to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        output = io.StringIO()
        table_name.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
        output.seek(0)
        contents = output.getvalue()
        cur.copy_from(output,'table_name', null="") 
        conn.commit()
```

***this is the old code when i didn’t create a function:***

```
CustomerTable.head(0).to_sql('CustomerTable', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False) 
conn = engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
output = io.StringIO()
CustomerTable.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur.copy_from(output, 'CustomerTable', null="") 
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have put `table_name` under quotations in your `to_sql` function.

Also, you seem to be tackling the issue of data model creation and maintenance, which already has a lot of tooling in Python around it. Consider using something like [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake i made is that the spilling was different, i had one with Capital latter and the other was small that’s why.

```
    cur.copy_from(output, name, null="")
```

in this line i was *passing* the table with **capital letter**. and it was wrong.

this is the correct code :

```
def save_database(tabelName, name):
    engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{b['username']}:{b['password']}@{b['host']}:{b['port']}/{b['database']}")
    tabelName.head(0).to_sql(name, engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    output = io.StringIO()
    tabelName.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
    output.seek(0)
    contents = output.getvalue()
    cur.copy_from(output, name, null="") 
    conn.commit()
```